# The 8 combinations of finitely axiomatizable for full, universal, and existential theories.

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be a signature (in the sense of model theory), and let $T$ be an $L$-theory. Also, let $T_\forall$ (respectively, $T_\exists$) be the deductive closure of the universal (respectively, existential) sentences of $T$. Prima facie, there are $8$ possible combinations of finite/non-finite axiomatizability for each of $T$, $T_\forall$, and $T_\exists$. For instance, they could all be finitely axiomatizable, or they could all be non-finitely axiomatizable, or $T_\forall$ could be finitely axiomatizable while both $T$ and $T_\exists$ are non-finitely axiomatizable, etc. My question is, which of these $8$ combinations are actually realized? In other words, for each of those $8$ combinations, I want either an example of a signature $L$ and a $L$-theory $T$ which is an example of that combination along with the proof that it is indeed an example, or, a proof that there is no signature $L$ and no $L$-theory $T$ which has that combination.

Comment: For which of the 8 combinations do you know an example already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are examples of all $8$ of the possible behaviors. I tried my best to give the simplest most "combinatorial" and transparent examples I could think of. If anyone has suggestions of simpler examples, I'd be happy to hear them (especially for cases 7 and 8, which are more complicated than I would like).

Note that any consistent existential sentence has a finite model. If $T$ has no finite model, then $T_\exists$ has no finite model (it includes the schema saying "there are more than $n$ elements" for every $n$), so $T_\exists$ is not finitely axiomatizable. We'll use this observation a few times.

1. $T$, $T_\forall$, $T_\exists$ all FA: The empty theory.
2. $T$, $T_\forall$, $T_\exists$ all $\lnot$FA: We can take any non-finitely-axiomatizable theory axiomatized by quantifier-free sentences, since then $T = T_\forall = T_\exists$. For example, in the language with a constant symbol $c$ and a unary function symbol $f$, $\{f^n(c)\neq c\mid n\in \omega\}$.
3. $T$ and $T_\exists$ $\lnot$FA, $T_\forall$ FA:  The theory of an infinite set (in the empty language). This is an existential theory, so $T = T_\exists$ is $\lnot$FA (since it has no finite models), and $T$ has no non-trivial universal consequences.
4. $T$ and $T_\forall$ $\lnot$FA, $T_\exists$ FA: Similarly to the last point, it suffices to find a $\lnot$FA universal theory with no non-trivial existential consequences. For example, in the language with a binary relation $R$, consider the theory which says "there is no $R$-cycle of length $n$" for all $n\in\omega$.
5. $T$ and $T_\forall$ FA, $T_\exists$ $\lnot$FA: The theory of non-empty dense linear orders without endpoints. $T$ is FA, and $T_\forall$ is the theory of linear orders, which is FA. $T$ has no finite models,  so $T_\exists$ is $\lnot$FA.
6. $T$ $\lnot$FA, $T_\forall$ and $T_\exists$ FA: Consider the language with a unary predicate $P$. Let $T$ have one axiom for each $n\in \omega$, which says $(\exists x\, P(x))\rightarrow (\exists^{\geq n} x\, \top)$. A model of $T$ is either a set in which no elements satisfy $P$ or an infinite set in which $P$ is interpreted arbitrarily. $T$ is not finitely axiomatizable, but it has no non-trivial universal or existential consequences.
7. $T$ and $T_\exists$ FA, $T_\forall$ $\lnot$FA: Consider the theory in the language with a unary relation $G$, a binary relation $R$, and a ternary relation $E$. The theory says: (1) If $R(a,b)$, then $G(a)$ and $G(b)$. (2) If $E(a,b,c)$, then $\lnot G(a)$, $G(b)$, and $G(c)$. (3) $R$ is a graph relation on $G$ (it is symmetric and antireflexive). (4) For all $a$ such that $\lnot G(a)$, $E(a,y,z)$ is an equivalence relation on $G$ with two classes, establishing a bipartition of the graph $(G,R)$. That is, for all $b$ and $c$, if $R(b,c)$, then $\lnot E(a,b,c)$. (5) There exists $a$ such that $\lnot G(a)$. I have given a finite axiomatization of $T$, and $T_\exists$ just says that there exists an element $x$ satisying $\lnot G(x)$, $\lnot R(x,x)$ and $\lnot E(x,x,x)$, so this is also finitely axiomatizable. But $T_\forall$ says, in addition to (1)-(4), that the graph $R$ has no $n$-cycles for all odd $n\geq 3$. The point is that the existence of a bipartition implies these conditions, but since $T_\forall$ can't ensure the existence of an element $a$ satisfying $\lnot G(a)$, so that $E(a,x,y)$ witnesses that the graph is bipartite, $T_\forall$ has to rule out odd cycles explicitly.
8. $T$ FA, $T_\forall$ and $T_\exists$ $\lnot$FA: The idea is to combine examples 5 and 7. Take the previous example (7), add a new binary relation symbol $<$, and add axioms asserting that $<$ is a dense linear order without endpoints on the set of $x$ satisfying $\lnot G(x)$. The same considerations as in 7 show that $T_\forall$ is not finitely axiomatizable. And now $T_\exists$ is not finitely axiomatizable, because $T$ has no finite models.